# Multi-threaded Application - SQL Query for Duplicate Check

Tags: java, sql, multithreading

I'm just looking for high-level advice when dealing with an issue with a multi-threaded application.

Here's how it works:

The application takes in `Alerts`, which are then processed in different threads to make `Reports`. On occasion, two `Alerts` include the same `Report`, however that is not desired.

It is a Spring application, written in Java, using a MySQL DB.

I altered my code to run a SELECT SQL query before saving a `Report` which checks to see if a similar report is already there. If it exists, the `Report` is not generated. However, if two `Alerts` come in at the same time, the SELECT command is run for `Report #2`, before `Report #1` is saved.

I thought about putting in a sleep() with a random wait time of 1-10 seconds, but it still would cause an issue when the two threads had the same random sleep time assigned.

I'm pretty new to multi-threading, so does anyone have any ideas? Or resources to point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have code that looks something like this:

```
Report report = getReport(...);  // calls the DB to get a record to see if it already exists
if (report == null) {
    insertReport(...);  // add a record to DB which might have already been added by another thread
}
```

then to avoid collisions across threads (or JVMs) combine the SELECT and INSERT.  For example:

```
 insertReportIfNotAlreadyExists(...);
```

which uses a query structured as:

```
INSERT INTO REPORTS (...) VALUES (...)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)
```

with the NOT EXISTS clause SELECTing for the record to make sure it doesn't already exist.

Comment: This sounds perfect. Now how to figure out how to do that with Hibernate haha.